# Dynamic dates in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure

I am trying to copy the data from the Azure SQL table to the CSV file in Azure Data Factory.
CSV Filename must be appended with below date
**Filename_11_07**

```
Where Filename --> comes from dynamic content
11 --> month
07 --> current date of last Sunday (Current date is 10th of Nov)
Would it be possible to manipulate the dates in dynamic content? Any other way to achieve this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are executing your pipeline every Wednesday, you can minus 3 from the current date and extract out the month and day from it. If your pipeline can run at any time, then the solution will be a bit more complicated.

You can replace Filename with whatever dynamic variable you would like to use.

```
@concat('Filename_',substring(getPastTime(3,'Day'),5,2),'_',substring(getPastTime(3,'Day'),8,2),'.csv')
```